# Linking Instances in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to put a link between two instances created on Instance on Points with the links not centrally located but rather on the edge of the instanced object. The problem comes with the fact that I want the objects to rotate independently (along one axis) and so the position that the links connect to changes.

A couple of screenshots below that are showing where I'd like the links to join to

[image]

[image]

End result would look like this with links between all elements

[image]

Comment: can u pls explain a bit more what your end goal is? do you wanna make something like a pearl necklace? or...? as far as i understood it currently i would use an armature...but...i think i didn't understood quite well

Comment: I've updated the original to show an image of how the links would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that we instantiate the individual objects with random rotation at the points of a grid. This should look something like this:

[image]

However, if now before instantiation these objects are sent through the node `Bounding Box`, instead of the objects we get a couple of beautiful cuboids, each corresponding to the dimensions of the original object and having 6 sides/faces. Also, the added rotation of the objects is taken over. This could then look something like this:

[image]

Now these cuboids have to be processed (before instantiation) with the node `Dual Mesh`, which converts faces to points and points to faces:

[image]

At the same time we split the grid on which we want to instantiate the objects with the node `Split Edges`, and scale these edges a bit.

[image]

Now that the individual edges are available and the beautiful structure we created earlier with the rotated objects, we only need to transfer the closest points of these to the points of the edges. To do this, the node `Transfer Attribute` is set to *Nearest*. With `Set Position` these positions are then transferred to the points of the edges:

[image]

If you then use the original objects at the points of the grid, you have the desired result:

[image]

And here is the corresponding node tree and the blend file:

[image]
[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @SaintPaulie You are welcome!